# mexGetArrayPtr not working as expected

Tags: matlab, mex

I have the following test_mex mex function:

```
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray **plhs, int nrhs, const mxArray **prhs)
{
  const mxArray* m_var = NULL;
  if ((m_var = mexGetArrayPtr("a", "caller")) == NULL)
  {
    mexErrMsgTxt("oopsie");
  }
}
```

And the following test.m file:

```
function test()
  a = 12345;
  test_mex();
```

- When I run it it always fails and prints "oopsie".
- When I make `a` a global and change the "caller" string in the mex function to "global" it works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Notes:

- this is a positively ancient version of matlab: Version 6.1.0.450 Release 12.1
- mexGetArrayPtr is the old version of mexGetVariablePtr and yes its argument order is different

Comment: Your code compiles and runs as expected on my machine, though I have to give the mex compiler a `-V5` option so it is compatible with `mexGetArrayPtr`. I'm using Matlab 7.5 (R2007b). Try to use `clear mex` before re-compilation, though I don't think this is the issue.

Comment: @Itamar The mex is c so it's compiled with the regular toolchain and the script is compiled with mcc, so I don't think environment should have anything to do with it. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I mentioned the version just for completeness. What is the 'regular toolchain'? Which compiler is defined to be used by 'mex'?

Comment: @Itamar, a mexsol is just a regular ELF shared object exposing a mexFunction symbol, so toolchain is cc and ld. And with "environment" I mean the clear mex reference, not the version.

Comment: now it's clearer, I didn't realize you are talking about Linux environment. I am not familiar with Matlab in Linux - In windows you can use the (Matlab) default compiler which is Lcc-win32, or define a non-default one. I used the default.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this example under version 6.1.0.450 on Solaris. The one thing I had to change was that

```
test_mex();
```

is a syntax error in older versions of MATLAB, and I needed to change it to

```
test_mex;
```

This worked (no error was produced). You mention that you are "compiling the script with mcc" in your comments. Do you mean you are compiling the test.m function with MCC? If I recall correctly, in R12.1, MCC-compiled M-code was turned into C code (for either MEX or standalone executable), and therefore did not have a "workspace" for mexGetArrayPtr to access. Essentially this was a limitation of the MCC compiler. I tried

```
mcc -x test.m
```

(which builds an MCC-generated MEX-file) with both the "caller" case and "global" case that you described and saw the "oopsie" error when using "caller" and no error when using "global", just as you described.

Comment: To clarify more, since this confused me when I was starting with MEX stuff: `mex` converts a *.c file which defines `mexFunction` into a shared library Matlab can call.  `mcc` converts (imperfectly) a *.m file to a *.c file which defines `mexFunction`.  `mcc` is not needed for ordinary cases of writing something in C and calling it from Matlab.